# Triviality of functions integrated against some trigonometrical kernels

Tags: real-analysis

Let's say we have a smooth real symmetric function $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$ satisfying next identity:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}(e^{-i\xi x}-e^{-i\xi y})f(x,y)\,dx\,dy=0\quad\forall \xi\in\mathbb{R}. $$

Do we have triviality (i.e. $f\equiv 0$)? Or there is a nontrivial counterexample? We are motivated by uniqueness of fractional problems.

Edit: While the answer of Iosif is definitely true, I think I should have ask the same question with $f$ begin anti-symmetric as this is less trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In fact, this identity holds for all integrable symmetric functions $f$.

Indeed, then, interchanging the variables $x$ and $y$, for all $\xi\in\Bbb R$ we have
$$\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-i\xi y}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy
=\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-i\xi x}f(y,x)\,dy\,dx
=\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-i\xi x}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy,$$
so that your identity holds.

---

The OP has now also asked: What if $f$ is anti-symmetric? Then, again assuming that $f$ is integrable and smooth, for all $\xi\in\Bbb R$ we will similarly have
$$\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-i\xi y}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy
=\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-i\xi x}f(y,x)\,dy\,dx
=-\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-i\xi x}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy,$$
so that
$$0=2\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-i\xi y}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy
=2\int_{\Bbb R}dy\,e^{-i\xi y}\int_{\Bbb R}dx\,f(x,y)
$$
or, equivalently,
$$\int_{\Bbb R}dx\,f(x,y)=0 \tag{10}\label{10}$$
for all real $y$.

E.g., if $f(x,y)=e^{-(x-y)^2}(x-y)$ for real $x$ and $y$, then $f$ is an anti-symmetric integrable smooth function and \eqref{10} holds for all real $y$, but $f$ is a not the zero function.

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely true, but what happens if $f$ is anti-symmetric?

Comment: @JingeonAn-Lacroix : This is now answered as well.